# Run nutch in OSGI environment

Tags: osgi, nutch, osgi-bundle

I am new to OSGI framwork So this question might seem silly.

Can we run Apache Nutch 1.4 in OSGI framework. I want to create an OSGI bundle of nutch. I am using eclipse indigo to compile the Nutch source code. So i think there should be some kind of plugin which can create OSGI bundle instead of jar after the compilation. I just need the OSGI bundle of Nutch.

I don't even know if it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look for a bundle that implements Nutch. A quick google turned up [this](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchOSGi). If this particular bundle doesn't meet your needs, you can just embed the Nutch dependency into one of your own bundles, using the Embed-Dependency field in your bundle's manifest.

Answer (score 1):

A bundle which already implements Nutch, as the other answer suggests, is your best bet. More generally, you can easily convert an existing jar into an OSGi bundle (without having the source code) using the [wrap](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Wrapping) function of the [bnd tool](http://www.aqute.biz/Code/Bnd). If you do have the source code and want to recompile, [maven's bundle plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) and the bundle packaging will generate bundles.

In the interests of modularity, which is one of OSGi's main drivers, I'd suggest using a separate Nutch bundle rather than embedding the dependency.